# How to update the state of SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

If I pause the synthesis and call SpeakAsyncCancel or SpeakAsyncCancelAll, the state of the SpeechSynthesizer object still returns the state as Paused.

Since the state is readonly, I cannot reset the state explicitly while cancelling.

Is there an alternate API which can be used to update the state?

Comment: Simply call Resume() after SpeakAsyncCancel if the state is paused.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `call Resume()`

It will resume the the synthesizer after you return